# Simple .NET Web App for managing family budget

Tags: c#, .net, ddd

I am creating some small project for my portfolio. It will be an app written in .NET and React but for now I've done backend part and I seek code review. I wanted it to be aligned with DDD principles and clean architecture. Can you review it and tell me is there any areas to improve to make it more readable and scalable? Here's [link for github repository](https://github.com/GustawOhler/FamilyBudget)

My main concern is keeping up with SRP (single responsibility principle). For example I have to create budgets and add new members to existing budget. I put those actions in single class which does these DB operations (using adequate repositories) but also authorize user rights to perform this action.

Here's one of my classes in application to handle saving, editing and deleting db objects, Budget Manager:

```
    public class BudgetManager : IBudgetManager
    {
        private readonly IRepository<Budget> _budgetRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<Category> _categoryRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<BalanceChange> _balanceChangeRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<User> _userRepository;
        private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
        private readonly IAuthorizationVerifier _authorizationVerifier;

        public BudgetManager(IRepository<Budget> budgetRepository, UserManager<User> userManager, IAuthorizationVerifier authorizationVerifier, IRepository<Category> categoryRepository, IRepository<BalanceChange> balanceChangeRepository, IRepository<User> userRepository)
        {
            _budgetRepository = budgetRepository;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _authorizationVerifier = authorizationVerifier;
            _categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
            _balanceChangeRepository = balanceChangeRepository;
            _userRepository = userRepository;
        }

        public async Task<Budget> AddBudgetMembers(NewBudgetMembersInput input)
        {
            var authUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(input.RequestingUserName);
            var budget = await _budgetRepository.GetSingleOrDefault(new BudgetSpecification(input.BudgetId));

            if (!_authorizationVerifier.IsAdmin(authUser, budget))
            {
                throw new AuthorizationException("User needs admin rights for this operation");
            }

            var newMembers = await _userRepository.List(new UserSpecification(input.UserIds));

            var concatMembers = budget.Members.ToList();
            concatMembers.AddRange(newMembers);
            budget.Members = concatMembers.Distinct().ToList();

            await _budgetRepository.Edit(budget);
            return budget;
        }

        public async Task<Budget> CreateBudget(NewBudgetInput input)
        {
            var authUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(input.AdminUsername);

            var budget = new Budget()
            {
                Name = input.Name,
                Balance = input.Balance,
                Admin = authUser
            };
            budget.Members.Add(authUser);

            await _budgetRepository.Add(budget);
            return budget;
        }
    }
```

Related model, Budget:

```
    public class Budget: IEntityBase
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; init; }
        public required string Name { get; set; }
        public float Balance { get; set; }
        public int AdminId { get; set; }
        public User? Admin { get; set; }
        public ICollection<User> Members { get; set; } = new List<User>();
        public ICollection<BalanceChange> BalanceChanges { get; } = new List<BalanceChange>();
    }
```

But I'm not sure if that's compliant with SRP. Because it creates budgets but also edits budgets. But from other POV creating class for every other type of operation on entity seems a little bit superfluous and requires developer to write a lot of repeating code (interface, class, DI for controller). Also repositories which are popular solution in DDD are often performing all CRUD operations.

Answer (score 2):

I personally do not feel it violates SRP by editing and deleting budgets.  I would expect a budget manager to be able to perform both of those things, as well as delete budgets.

What I do take exception with is that from the small amount of code posted, that there is no way of knowing that all of your Balances, etc., are based on a `float` or `Single`.  A `float` has only 7 significant digits of precision and cannot exactly represent non-integers.  Any app dealing with money or current really should be using the base-10 `Decimal` type.  And I had to go digging into your GitHub to stumble upon this.

Comment: That's true, I should have probably added also Budget class to show how model looks. That's a little bit stupid because despite I used Decimal before I didn't know that it is base 10, thanks for that.